# Array of pointers pointing to a struct variable

Tags: c

I am getting errors for the below code as

(18) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

(18) : error C2227: left of '->str' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

(20) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

(20) : error C2227: left of '->str' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

I have declared the *p as a pointer to the struct in the main function.
I could not identify where i have done the mistake.Isnt *p similar to *p+0?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct s1{
        char *str;
        struct s1 *ptr;
    };
    static struct s1 arr[]={{"Bangalore",arr+1},{"Hyderabad",arr+2},{"Kerala",arr}};
    struct s1 *p[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        p[i]=arr[i].ptr;
    printf("\n%s"(*p)->str);
    printf("\n%s",(++*p)->str);
    printf("\n%s"((*p)++)->str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at your calls to `printf()` (which appears to be what the errors are actually referring to).  `"\n%s"(*p)->str` is not a valid expression, nor is `"\n%s"((*p)++)->str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are missing commas in your code:

```
printf("\n%s"(*p)->str);
...
printf("\n%s"((*p)++)->str);
```

Should have been:

```
printf("\n%s", (*p)->str);
...
printf("\n%s", ((*p)++)->str);
```

Are they just missing in the code you post here, or also on your real code?

Comment: :Yeah correctly pointed out. I missed the comma.Now i could get the output.I have a doubt in this question.Is *p[0] and *p are the same. Wont *p is like a base pointer for the array of pointers that cannot be changed with increment?

Comment: @Beata: the expressions `(++*p)` and `((*p)++)` aren't incrementing `p` (which is an array), they are incrementing the pointer that happens to be in the first element of the array named `p`.

Comment: @Michael:Thanks michael.Is this what i thought is right that incrementing *p (i.e. (++*p) and ((*p)++)) will point to *p[1].